# numpy array access

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create a numpy array of N elements, but I want to access the
array with an offset Noff, i.e. the first element should be at Noff and
not at 0. In C this is simple to do with some simple pointer arithmetic, i.e.
I malloc the array and then define a pointer and shift it appropriately.

Furthermore, I do not want to allocate N+Noff elements, but only N elements.

Now for numpy there are many methods that come to my mind:

(1) define a wrapper function to access the array
(2) overwrite the [] operator
(3) etc

But what is the fastest method to realize this?

Thanks a lot!
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already given (1) and (2) as both more or less sensible methods.  To test speed for these kind of things try `timeit` magic function in `ipython`.  Example usage:

```
A = array(range(10))
Noff = 2
wrapper_access = lambda i: A[i - Noff]
print wrapper_access(2)   #0
print wrapper_access(11)  #9
print wrapper_access(1)   #9 = A[-1]
timeit wrapper_access(5)
```

On my machine I get output from timeit `10000000 loops, best of 3: 193 ns per loop`

Answer (score 2):

Use `A[n-offset]`. this turns `offset` to `offset+len(A)` into `0` to `len(A)`.

Comment: the simplest solution.  but be wary that accessing offset-1 and below will wrap around to the other end of the array.

Answer (score 2):

I would be very cautious about over-riding the `[]` operator through the `__getitem__()` method. Although it will be fine with your own code, I can easily imagine that when the array gets passed to an arbitrary library function, you could get problems.

For example, if the function explicitly tried to get all values in the array as `A[0:-1]`, it would maps to `A[offset:offset-1]`, which will be an empty array for any positive or negative value of `offset`. This may be a little contrived, but it illustrates the general problem.

Therefore, I would suggest that you create a wrapper function for your own use (as a member function may be most convenient), but don't muck around with `__getitem__()`.